# Hide Addon Tab Globally in Storybook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I wish to hide an Addon Tab globally (not per story).  I don't wish to disable the addon itself, just hide its tab panel.

I'm using version 5.3.18 of Storybook with React and the addon tab I wish to hide is from addon "styled-component theme".

Sorry, I know this sounds a basic question but I just can't find out how to do this.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I'm unsure how to disable the addon bar - though it would be a nice to have. **However** if you want to disable one particular addon globally then the following should work. You could then do the below with all of your addons.

Assuming you want to disable the `controls` addon.

```
/* preview.ts */

export const parameters = {
  controls: { disabled: true },
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean the panel instead of the controls addon ?
You can configure this in the .storybook/manager.js file like this:

```
// .storybook/manager.js

import { addons } from '@storybook/addons';     
  
addons.setConfig({
    options: {showPanel: false}
});
```

There will be no more panel at the bottom of your stories :) Only when your single story has this parameter:

```
parameters={{ options: {showPanel: true} }}
```

It will show up again.